# How to perform bulk tag update operations in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, hstore

I have a table in my Postgres 9.6 database which has tags. I wish these tags to be stored in a single column rather than normalized into a separate tags table.

I need to be able to perform bulk tag updates; eg "update things add tag1,tag2,tag3" or "update things remove tag1,tag2,tag3". I'm struggling to formulate these queries. What's the best way to do this?

Some experimentation I've performed using different column types to represent tags:

#### Column type JSONB, storing array

This seems very natural from a programming perspective, and maps easily to a Set object in my entity model. But Postgres doesn't seem to have an operator that will remove more than one tag:

```
select '["tag1", "tag2"]'::jsonb - 'tag1';            -- works
select '["tag1", "tag2"]'::jsonb - '["tag1"]'::jsonb; -- doesn't work
```

Also how can I peform a union that dedupliates?

```
select '["tag1", "tag2"]'::jsonb || '["tag2", "tag3"]'; -- tag2 twice!
```

#### Column type TEXT[]

This seems to have all the same problems as JSONB arrays. I don't see "set difference" or "set union" functions. But maybe there's a way of creating these functions?

#### Column type HSTORE

Store as {"key"=>true} or some other ignored value and just test for key existence. This actually seems to work; there are union and difference operators for keys:

```
select '"tag1" => true, "tag2" => true' - '"tag1" => true, "tag2" => true'; -- works!
select '"tag1" => true, "tag2" => true' || '"tag2" => true, "tag3" => true'; -- works, no dupes!
```

This is a mild PITA for my ORM and it would be mildly annoying having to use the `akeys`/`skeys` functions all the time in queries. But at least my bulk update queries are straightforward.

Also, assuming someone figures out the difference/union functions for JSONB arrays or text arrays, would the bulk updates for HSTORE perform significantly better?

#### Column type JSONB, storing object

I thought maybe the HSTORE-like approach (eg `{keyname: true}`) could be used with JSONB, but I don't see a similar set of functions/operators for union and difference. This would also be a mild annoyance to map with the ORM. I guess the only reason to prefer this over HSTORE is my fear that HSTORE will be abandoned someday, but JSONB lacks the same features.

What should I do? Is there a good way of crafting union/difference operators for the JSONB or TEXT[] types? Or should I just fallback to HSTORE?

Comment: Reading through https://github.com/JDBurnZ/postgresql-anyarray makes HSTORE look better and better.

Comment: Yes, but... https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2017.html#July_11_2017